# Android RecycleView Add or Enable ScrollBar Programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollbar, vertical-scroll

I am designing RecycleView programmatically without using XML,
So I can reuse this code in all projects by just coping the Java file.
Help me to enable scroll bar.
Also how to I get alphabet scroll bar like in contacts app without using any third party API.

```
RecyclerView recyclerVyuVar = new RecyclerView(this);
recyclerVyuVar.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

recyclerVyuVar.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
recyclerVyuVar.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Two full day of struggle I developed Alphabetical Scroll Bar Programatically like in contacts.

U can modify the code and fit based on your requirements.
NamSrnVcc can be any Name of the Activity or Screen you are using.

If u need to place the List View or Recycler View Place it inside the Super Relative layout NamSupRloVav

```
NamLysLyoVav = new RecyclerView(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.SolBarVid));

NamLysAdrVar = new NamLysAdrCls(GetAllNamAryLysFnc());
NamLysLyoVav.setAdapter(NamLysAdrVar);
NamLysLyoVav.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

NamSupRloVav.addView(NamLysLyoVav);
```

This is to help all whom I wish not to struggle like me.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.graphics.Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG;

public class NamSrnVcc extends Activity
{
    RelativeLayout NamSupRloVav;
    ImageView ZumTxtImjVav;
    String AlpAryVar[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    float DpsVal;
    int GetDpsValFnc(int IntPsgVal)
    {
        return (int) (IntPsgVal * DpsVal);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.srn_nam_uic);

        DpsVal = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        NamSupRloVav = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.NamSrnLyoUid);

        LinearLayout AlpSolBarLloVav = new LinearLayout(this);
        AlpSolBarLloVav.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        GradientDrawable AlpSolBarGrdDrwablVaj = new GradientDrawable();
        AlpSolBarGrdDrwablVaj.setStroke(2,Color.GRAY);
        AlpSolBarGrdDrwablVaj.setCornerRadius(20);
        AlpSolBarLloVav.setBackground(AlpSolBarGrdDrwablVaj);
        AlpSolBarLloVav.setPadding(GetDpsValFnc(10),GetDpsValFnc(5),GetDpsValFnc(10),GetDpsValFnc(5));
        AlpSolBarLloVav.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View VyuPsgVal, MotionEvent MsnEvtPsgVar)
            {
                switch (MsnEvtPsgVar.getActionMasked())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ZumTxtImjVav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        TskTdoAftTchFnc(VyuPsgVal, MsnEvtPsgVar);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        TskTdoAftTchFnc(VyuPsgVal, MsnEvtPsgVar);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("TAG", "onTouch: ACTION_UP");
                        ZumTxtImjVav.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            void TskTdoAftTchFnc(View VyuPsgVal, MotionEvent MsnEvtPsgVar)
            {
                LinearLayout AlpSolLloVav = (LinearLayout)VyuPsgVal;
                float AlpTxtHytVal = AlpSolLloVav.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
                float TchYcoVal = MsnEvtPsgVar.getY();
                int AlpIdxVal = (int) (TchYcoVal / AlpTxtHytVal);
                if(AlpIdxVal >= 0 && AlpIdxVal < AlpAryVar.length)
                    ZumTxtImjVav.setImageBitmap(DevImjBmpFrmTxtFnc(AlpAryVar[AlpIdxVal], Color.MAGENTA));
            }
        });

        for(String AlpIdxVar : AlpAryVar)
        {
            TextView AlpIdxTxtVav = new TextView(this);
            AlpIdxTxtVav.setText(AlpIdxVar);
            AlpIdxTxtVav.setTextSize(10);
            AlpIdxTxtVav.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            int DpsVal = GetDpsValFnc(2);
            AlpIdxTxtVav.setPadding(DpsVal,DpsVal,DpsVal,DpsVal);
            AlpIdxTxtVav.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            AlpIdxTxtVav.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            AlpSolBarLloVav.addView(AlpIdxTxtVav);
        }


        ZumTxtImjVav = new ImageView(this);
        GradientDrawable ZumTxtImjGrdDrwablVar = new GradientDrawable();
        ZumTxtImjGrdDrwablVar.setCornerRadius(100);
        ZumTxtImjGrdDrwablVar.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        ZumTxtImjVav.setBackground(ZumTxtImjGrdDrwablVar);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ZumTxtImjVyuRulVaj = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        ZumTxtImjVyuRulVaj.setMarginStart(20);
        ZumTxtImjVyuRulVaj.setMarginEnd(20);
        ZumTxtImjVyuRulVaj.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        ZumTxtImjVav.setLayoutParams(ZumTxtImjVyuRulVaj);
        NamSupRloVav.addView(ZumTxtImjVav);
        ZumTxtImjVav.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams AlpSolBarLyoRulVaj = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        AlpSolBarLyoRulVaj.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        AlpSolBarLyoRulVaj.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        AlpSolBarLyoRulVaj.rightMargin = 10;
        NamSupRloVav.addView(AlpSolBarLloVav, AlpSolBarLyoRulVaj);
    }

    Bitmap DevImjBmpFrmTxtFnc(String TxtSrgPsgVal, int TxtClrPsgVal)
    {
        int TxtSyzVal = 100;
        TextPaint PenPytVaj = new TextPaint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        PenPytVaj.setTextSize(TxtSyzVal);
        PenPytVaj.setColor(TxtClrPsgVal);
        PenPytVaj.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

        Rect TxtRctVar = new Rect();
        PenPytVaj.getTextBounds(TxtSrgPsgVal, 0, TxtSrgPsgVal.length(), TxtRctVar);
        Bitmap TxtImjBmpVar = Bitmap.createBitmap(TxtSyzVal * 2, TxtSyzVal * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas ImjCanvasVaj = new Canvas(TxtImjBmpVar);
        float XcoVal = ImjCanvasVaj.getWidth() / 2 - TxtRctVar.width() / 2  - TxtRctVar.left;
        float YcoVal = ImjCanvasVaj.getHeight() / 2 + TxtRctVar.height() / 2  - TxtRctVar.bottom;
        ImjCanvasVaj.drawText(TxtSrgPsgVal, XcoVal, YcoVal, PenPytVaj);
        return TxtImjBmpVar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable ScrollBar programatically you'll need to declare a style:

```
<style name="ScrollbarRecyclerView" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
</style>
```

And to initialize your RecyclerView use ContextThemeWrapper:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.ScrollbarRecyclerView
```

Comment: Can we do R.style.ScrollbarRecyclerView aslo programatically, Bcoz I want to just want to copy single Java Code everywhere in all projects and dont want anything in xml.